# Does `pantheon-files` support extensions and plugins?

Tags: pantheon-files

Does `pantheon-files` support extensions and plugins, like nautilus do.

If yes, please mention *few* extensions or let me know (provide link ) where can I get those list of *all* extensions.

---

In nautilus I was able to get the list of extensions by the command:

```
wajig search nautilus | grep extens
```

The above way not working for pantheon-files.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too broad. Sub Firefox for Files here to see why. It's not practical to attempt to list any and every possible 3rd party extension.

Comment: @DanielForé I've rephrased the question by using part of the body text. How to list extensions and how to install them are two separate questions.

Comment: @DanielForé Dan sorry, I _really_ don't understand the comment except _close_ reason, can you provide answer now

Comment: I don't think this question is particularly answerable. I don't think it's possible to list all possible Files extensions, especially because Files implements contractor.

Comment: @Ravan If you change the main question to be the one you finish with, then it would be possible to answer. Right now, there is no way to list all possible extensions.

Comment: @LewisGoddard ok, I will edit :)

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is ***actions that can be triggered from the context menu of the file manager, after selecting one or more files or folders***, I don't know if the proper name is *"extensions"*, but `.contract` files can be created in `usr/share/contract` to add context menu entries to Pantheon-Files.

So, the general answer to your question is "**Yes**". But if you mean whether you can find ready-made `.contract` files on the internet to download and use, the answer is rather negative.

---

**About mentioning *all* of them:**

I suppose the list you get in Nautilus with the command you mention is the list of scripts/extensions that are already installed.

To see the one present in Pantheon Files take a look in `/usr/share/contractor`.

As said in a comment, there is no exhaustive list for these context-menu actions: first, because, as far as I can tell for the moment, there are no such ready-made `.contract` files to be found on the internet available for download, as you have for Nautilus or Thunar; second, as they **can be created** for the specific commands that you want applied to different files or folders, they are too many to list, because they are as many as the possible applicable commands that may involve different executable files/scripts.

---

**About mentioning a *few* of them:**

Some of the ones I have used: some to play/open in different programs, to convert, to extract audio without conversion, to display media info or mime-type, to run an executable file, to search, to join... Most of these are mentioned on this site or on U&L stackexchange. (For example: [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3295/170), [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/264/170), [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/49/170) or [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3788/170); also: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192158/32012)). If you need a certain context-menu action in Files, you can search on such sites or post here a question asking for that.

---

To create a new one the procedure is something similar to the following one, an example which adds a search option with *Catfish*:

With `gedit` as text editor:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/contractor/catfish_search.contract
```

Paste this:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Search Here
Description=Find files
MimeType=inode;
Exec=catfish --path=%f %U
```

Save and close text editor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To avoid using sudo, you can put custom contracts in your home directory, under ~/.local/share/contractor.   These take precendence.

Comment: @JeremyWootten - of course, thanks for reminding me, I have edited the answer

Comment: @cipricus Any change you're willing to maybe add some documentation to the Contractor repo? See: https://github.com/elementary/contractor/issues/16